# How to resolve Jsoup Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception?

Tags: android, html, arrays, jsoup

Trying to get data from website through HTML parsing.

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0

Why is the array empty?

I included only the class that contains Jsoup because im sure the error is in it. And also i included the HTML part of the website in case you guys wanna take a look at it.

**Jsoup Class**

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;


public class contentExcluding {



    public String[] createData(final String [] text, final String [] pictures)
    {

        Runnable rMain = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://egyptianstreets.com/").get();
                    Element content = doc.getElementById("featured-multi-main-img");
                    Elements headlines = content.getElementsByTag("img");
                    Elements img = content.getElementsByAttribute("src");
                    String x = img.toString();
                    pictures[0] = x;
                    text[0] = x;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(rMain);
        t.start();

        return pictures;
    }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="head-wrap" class="left relative">
        <div class="head-wrap-out">
            <div class="head-wrap-in">
                                <div id="featured-multi-wrap" class="left relative">
                                    <div id="featured-multi-main" class="left relative">
                        <a href="http://egyptianstreets.com/2016/08/06/egyptian-rowers-nadia-negm-and-abdel-khalek-elbana-reach-quarter-finals-at-olympics/" rel="bookmark">
                        <div id="featured-multi-main-img" class="left relative">
                                                            <img width="1000" height="512" src="http://egyptianstreets.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/pablo-2-1000x512.png" class="unlazy reg-img wp-post-image" alt="pablo (2)" />                             <img width="400" height="240" src="http://egyptianstreets.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/pablo-2-400x240.png" class="unlazy mob-img wp-post-image" alt="pablo (2)" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It looks like `pictures` or `text` are 0 length arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Check that you initialized them (before call `createData` method) with a higher size of 0.

Example:

```
String[] pictures = contentExcluding.createData(new String[1], new String[1]);
```

Comment: I understand the error but the problem is that the Jsoup class returns null to the array so its empty.

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException has nothing to do with whether the content is null or not.  @Davide is right, you need to initialize your arrays correctly.